# this.setState() is not a function Class Component of React and image with fileReader()

Tags: reactjs, class, this, setstate

I can't understand why this.setState doesn't work, if I have it binding on top. I would really appreciate a hand with this.

```
class Register extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state= {
      profilePic:"", 
    }

    this.Handleimage= this.Handleimage.bind(this);

  }

  Handleimage(e){
     var file = e.target.files[0]
    if(file) {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        this.setState({
          profilePic: this.result
        })
      })
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    } 
  }

 <input  type="file"  label="Foto de perfil" name='profilePic' onChange={(e)=> this.Handleimage(e)}/>
```

Comment: Judging by the `this.result` reference I'm going to assume the added event listener is referencing a different `this` than that of your react component.

Comment: Regular functions (`function (..) {...}` ) and arrow functions (`(...) => {...}`) have different definitions of `this`. Long story short, regular functions have their own `this` context, whereas arrow functions use their existing context for `this`. So change it to `"load", () => {` and it should fix it

Comment: Thanks my frend.I tried everything and this ended up being the solution. I thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that functions have their own this. In your implementation the `this` appears to be in the context of the reader and not your react component.

You could instead use the `reader.onload` callback and read from the load event. This works for me for grabbing an image file from my local machine and rendering it.

[FileReader.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload)

> The **`FileReader.onload`** property contains an event handler executed when
> the `load` event is fired, when content read with readAsArrayBuffer,
> readAsBinaryString, ***readAsDataURL*** or readAsText is available.

```
Handleimage(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.setState({ profilePic: event.target.result });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

[image: Edit this-setstate-is-not-a-function-class-component-of-react-and-image-with-filere]